# Flask + Dash App integration using DispatcherMiddleware - gunicorn vs flask run

Tags: python, flask

I am using DispatcherMiddleware to integrate and serve both Flask and Dash Apps. I am able to launch the flask app using `flask run` command, but not Dash App.

When I use gunicorn, I am able to run both Apps.

Any ideas on why that would be the case? I don't know enough about flask namescaping.

Answer (score 0):

You must register the dash app, call the callback from layout to flask, in example

**dash.py**

```
# import you initialize flask create_app
from app import create_app
server = create_app()
```

**init.py**

```
import dash
from dash import server
from your.dashapp1.layout import layout
from your.dashapp1.callbacks import register_callbacks

app = Flask(__name__)

dashapp1 = dash.Dash(
        __name__,
        server=app,
        url_base_pathname="/path-to-dash-app/",
        assets_folder=get_root_path(__name__) + "/dashboard/assets/",
        external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
        meta_tags=[meta_viewport],
    )

    with app.app_context():
        dashapp1.title = "Report Visualization"
        dashapp1.layout = layout
        register_callbacks(dashapp1)
```

so when you run the flask app, the dash app will be run too, and you can access the dash app in `/path-to-dash-app/`